# Laravel - ensure all relationships fulfilled

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 4.2. I'm currently working on a shopping cart, where some `Product`s have some `Attribute`s that require to be filled out before it can be added to cart (such as color, size, model, etc). Some don't have any required attributes.

The request is a product and a comma separated list of attributes (or null). Basically what I'm doing now is looping through all ProductAttributes for a product and seeing if one of the items in the array matches that attribute. If we come to a ProductAttribute that isn't in the array, the request fails.

Two things: 1) It works but is there a better way in Laravel to do this? 2) I know it seems silly but if a request contains all valid attributes plus additional attributes (or overlapping attributes) the request is still marked as valid. Is there a better way than the way I've written out?

Comment: Please show us the code you currently have

Comment: I don't really think there is "Laravel way" of doing this, since this is just a very specific logic your product have. Probably the ideal way would be add that validation in your product model.

Comment: Just get the required attributes as an array and make sure they are present in the input.